# Get correct datatype of prepared statement using ParameterMetaData in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, metadata

I have to fetch parameter name and parameter datatype from the prepared statement in **MySQL** Database. So for that i have used **ParameterMetaData** class. But now i am getting wrong **datatype**. this is giving only **"VARCHAR"** datatype. When i searched this query on the internet,I found

> "Returns the parameter type. java.sql.Types.VARCHAR is returned if the data type is not known".

Now what should i do for getting correct **datatype**. Please help me if possible.

Here is my code :-

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = getMySqlConnection();

        String query = "select * from survey where id > ? and name = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ParameterMetaData paramMetaData = pstmt.getParameterMetaData();
        if (paramMetaData == null) {
          System.out.println("db vendor does NOT support ParameterMetaData");
        } else {
          System.out.println("db vendor supports ParameterMetaData");
          String paramTypeName = paramMetaData.getParameterTypeName(1);
          String paramTypeName1 = paramMetaData.getParameterTypeName(2);
          System.out.println("param SQL type name=" + paramTypeName);
          System.out.println("param SQL type name1=" + paramTypeName1);

        }

        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();

      }


    public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
      }
```

this is giving output :-

> param SQL type name= VARCHAR
>    param SQL type name1= VARCHAR

But I am expecting this output :-

> param SQL type name= INTEGER
>    param SQL type name1= VARCHAR

thanks in advance

Comment: Its hard to tell what the output really should be if you don't include your `survey` schema.

Answer (score 0):

To get complete result use `getParameterClassName(int param)` instead of `getParameterTypeName`

refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html#getParameterClassName%28int%29

Hope this helps